# warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning superClass to subClass

Tags: objective-c, subclass, superclass

Assume a valid super class, and a valid subclass ie the classes work.

the following line in a constructor of the subclass
self = [super init] ;

throws the following warning
// warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct Animal *', expected 'struct Cat *'

Any ideas on how to fix this and remove the warning ?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you provide a custom init-Method in your superclass?

Check the return type of this method. Is it (Animal *)? If so, change this to (id).

Init methods should return (id)

Comment: Thanks fluchtpunkt.
Changed to (id)
<http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocAllocInit.html>